# How to disable link in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is actually a 2 part question.

1) I'm having trouble at the moment looping through my links and disabling it with javascript. I need to grab the links from a div id called "bottom" and any link with "nhl" in it needs to be disabled or just won't work however you want to word it. So far i've got: External js file.

```
onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementById("bottom").getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].indexOf("nhl") >= 0) {
            links[i].onclick = function() {
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

html file:

```
<div id="bottom" class="change">
<a href="http://www.nhl.com/">www.nhl.com</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">www.youtube.com</a>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">www.w3schools.com</a>
</div>
```

2) My js file at the moment contains a couple functions like:

```
function changeColorOnMouseIn() {
    this.style.color = "red";
}

function changeColourOnMouseOut() {
    this.style.color = "black";
}

onload = function() {
    var divClasses = querySelectorAll(".change p");

    for(i = 0; i < divClasses.length; i++) {
        divClasses[i].onmouseover = changeColorOnMouseIn;
        divClasses[i].onmouseout = changeColorOnMouseOut;
    }
}
```

My question is should I continue to do it this way or doing something like this instead:

```
onload = function() {
    var divClasses = document.querySelectorAll(".change p");

    for(i = 0; i < divClasses.length; i++) {
        divClasses[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.color = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

Or should I just make a function that does all that with the for loops and just call "myFunctionName()" in the onload function? What are the differences? And in what situation would you do one over the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **first part** I found a small mistake in your loop, you need to write links[i].href.indexOf("nhl")

```
onload = function() {
var links = document.getElementById("bottom").getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
       if(links[i].href.indexOf("nhl") >= 0) {// CHANGE
           links[i].onclick = function() {
                return false;
               }
           }
    }
 }
```

For the **second part** you can easily do it by CSS

```
.change p {
  color: black;
}
.change p:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

If you still want to do it in javascript then this approach is better

```
function changeColorOnMouseIn() {
    this.style.color = "red";
}

function changeColourOnMouseOut() {
    this.style.color = "black";
}

onload = function() {
    var divClasses = querySelectorAll(".change p");

    for(i = 0; i < divClasses.length; i++) {
        divClasses[i].onmouseover = changeColorOnMouseIn;
        divClasses[i].onmouseout = changeColorOnMouseOut;
    }
}
```

The reason here why this approach is better to the approach is because below code will create n number of anonymous function, so if loop is going for 10 items there will be 10 anonymous function, whole in above approach it will have single function declaration.

```
divClasses[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.color = "red";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand I can do it with CSS, but I am required to do it in Javascript.

Comment: @Stanza I hope I have answered your question

Comment: Yes that helps, but is there a reason why to that approach is better compared to the other ones?